# Charset conversion issue in mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I have a table with latin1 columns:

> CREATE TABLE `table_latin` (
> `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> `char_id` char(6) NOT NULL,
> `v` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
> KEY `char_id` (`char_id`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

> insert into table_latin (char_id, v) values (‘aaaa’, ‘bbbb’);

> set names utf8mb3; (sets connection_character_set/ collation = ‘utf8mb3’);

> SELECT char_id FROM `table_latin` UNION ALL SELECT 'N/A'

This works perfectly fine. Since the table column char_id has lower coercibility (2) compared to that of the literal string ‘N/A’ (4), the utf8mb3 literal string gets converted to latin1 (since both have only ascii repertoire).

However, on executing slightly modified form of the query:

```
    > SELECT char_id FROM `table_latin` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'N/A') a
```

It throws the following error:
Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb3_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'UNION'

If I check the coercibility of the nested query, it is still 4.

> SELECT coercibility(a.test) FROM (SELECT 'N/A' as ‘test’) a
> >   4

By theory the charset of the second entity must be converted to latin1. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem, and I think it might be an instance of this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94988

The bug report demonstrates the issue with a `JOIN`, but I was able to reproduce it with a `UNION`, like your example, in MySQL 8.0.35 (it did not happen in MySQL 5.7.44).

As suggested in the bug report, one way to avoid the error is to use a [character set introducer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-introducer.html) in the literal string, so that it uses the same character set as the column. In your example, it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT char_id
FROM table_latin
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (
  -- Add character set introducer _latin1 to match `char_id` column character set.
  SELECT _latin1'N/A'
) a
```

But I think your understanding is correct, and this doesn't seem to be expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

convert the string literal at subquery to `latin1`; using the `CONVERT()`

```
SELECT char_id FROM `table_latin` UNION ALL SELECT CONVERT('N/A' USING latin1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my question is:
> SELECT char_id FROM `table_latin` UNION ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'N/A') a.
This should work according to mysql docs since the two elements have different coercibility, ie charset of 'N/A' should implicitly change to latin1, which works perfectly fine if I remove the select * from wrapper ie:
> SELECT char_id FROM table_latin UNION ALL SELECT 'N/A';

Why is the select * from wrapper disallowing the change ? I encountered this issue while running a query in production server (we have a requirement for wrapping similarly inside subquery).